# SCAN with condition by additional column

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to solve the case.
Imagine that we have several of empty jars with different volume. Also, we have some other, mostly smaller, different cups filled with 2 different liquids: A and B. We need to pour liquid A from filled cups into empty jars in exact turn, and find out which jar we begin filling and which we finish filling with each cup with liquid A.

Here is the [sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KXxVYhlsmI--49ZGH8UHv5ldKiM77mrkHMiCFUvvtTA/edit?usp=sharing). With help, I solved this case with only one liquid like this

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(LET(x,XLOOKUP(SCAN(,{1;ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(A2:A,ROWS(A2:A)-1,1)},LAMBDA(a,c,a+c)),SCAN(,{F2:F},LAMBDA(a,c,a+c)),{E2:E},,1,2),y,XLOOKUP(SCAN(,A2:A,LAMBDA(a,c,a+c)),SCAN(,{F2:F},LAMBDA(a,c,a+c)),{E2:E},,1,2),IF(A2:A="",,HSTACK(x,y))))
```

But now I need to make with two. I tried to play with LAMBDA in SCAN, but it didn't help. As far as I understand, I can't add conditions to SCAN based on one column. I tried to replace SCAN with MMULT, and it helps with **finish filling jar** column, but not with first one. I'm stuck. Please, help.

Comment: Hello! You've solved then the scenario from your shared spreadsheet?, could you illustrate and show some manually-entered expected output to show how it would work with two liquids?

Comment: Hi. I solved "case1" tab in "solution1" tab. But there is case2 in next tab, which I need to solve.

Comment: Coming back to your liquids analogy, are we assuming that there is a second set of containers to be filled with liquid B which are the same size as the first set to be filled with liquid A, or have I misunderstood your scenario?

Comment: It may be, but we can ignore it, because it would be the same way as A one. Like two more columns for the second type of jars with almost the same formula.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one possible solution, plese test it out:

```
=MAP(A2:A,B2:B,LAMBDA(liquid,volume,
LET(filled,SUMIF(A2:liquid,liquid,B2:volume),
jarvols,SCAN(0,TOCOL(H2:H,1),LAMBDA(a,v,a+v)),
{XLOOKUP(filled-volume+1,jarvols,TOCOL(G2:G,1),,1),XLOOKUP(filled,jarvols,TOCOL(G2:G,1),,1)})))
```

[image]

You could possibly work with two SCANs to solve this, and it would be more efficient if you're working with really a lot of data; but this solution will let you solve it with any amount of different liquids:

With explanations:

```
=MAP(A2:A,B2:B,LAMBDA(liquid,volume,
LET(filled,SUMIF(A2:liquid,liquid,B2:volume), --> it calculates the filled volume up to this point
jarvols,SCAN(0,TOCOL(H2:H,1),LAMBDA(a,v,a+v)), --> it calculates the column of cumulative jars
{XLOOKUP(filled-volume+1,jarvols,TOCOL(G2:G,1),,1),XLOOKUP(filled,jarvols,TOCOL(G2:G,1),,1)}))) --> it looks up twice in the jars volumes. The starting point which is the total amount minus the local amount (filled-volume+1), and the final point (filled) --> you may want to change that '+1' if needed to a smaller value. I put it for the case when the previous jar is completely filled
```

---

UPDATE

I thought you needed independent sums, but if you just need to hide, here it goes another option, in blue in the picture:

```
=LET(volumes,SCAN(0,B2:B,LAMBDA(a,v,IF(OFFSET(v,0,-1)="A",a+v,a))),
jars,TOCOL(G2:G,1),
jarsvols,SCAN(0,TOCOL(H2:H,1),LAMBDA(a,v,a+v)),
MAP(volumes,TOCOL(B2:B,1),A2:A,LAMBDA(filled,start,type,IF(type<>"A",{"",""},{XLOOKUP(filled-start+1,jarsvols,jars,,1),XLOOKUP(filled,jarsvols,jars,,1)}))))
```

It checks if the value in A is equal to "A" with OFFSET in the SCAN at the beginning; if it isn't, it doesn't sum it. And in MAP it also checks if it's A, and create an empty row if it isn't {"",""}

[image]

Comment: Nice one, thanks a lot! Looks like it works. Only need to hide B results. I'll try to understand it and update